# Model Ownership Checking

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

In my Controller before a Model is modified (*updated or deleted*) I am trying to verify that the User performing the action actually owns the object they are trying to modify.

I am currently doing this at the method level and it seems a bit redundant.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Notebook notebook)
{
    if (notebook.UserProfileId != WebSecurity.CurrentUserId) { return HttpNotFound(); }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(notebook).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(notebook);
}
```

Is there a generic way of doing this that could be reusable across various models?

Is it possible to do this with an `ActionFilter`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see one problem with what you have - you are relying on user input to perform the security check.

Consider your code

```
if (notebook.UserProfileId != WebSecurity.CurrentUserId)
```

Notebook has come from model binding. So UserProfileId has come from model binding. And you can quite happily fake that - for example I use Firefox's TamperData to change the value of the hidden UserProfileId to match my login and away I go.

What I end up doing (in a service, rather than the controller) is on a post pulling back the record from the database based on the unique id passed (Edit/2 for example would use 2), and then checking User.Identity.Name (well, the passed identity parameter) against the current owner field I have in my returned database record.

Because I pull back from the database (repository, whatever) an attribute isn't going to work for this, and I'm not sure you could be generic enough in an attribute's approach anyway.

Comment: Wouldn't adding [Bind(Exclude="UserProfileID")] prevent that from being changed by the model binding?  Ideally I would like to be returning a ViewModel that doesn't contain any ID fields and just have those stored in TempData or something (not quite sure)...

Comment: Yes it would, but then where would it come from? :)

Comment: Yeah, I guess I hadn't really thought that out.  Like I said, I would like to return a ViewModel that does not contain any id fields I just don't know where to store that ID temporarily in MVC between calls - other than using Session >:).... That way I could return my POCO to the Controller and use AutoMapper or something hydrate the ViewModel.

Answer (score 5):

A filter approach might look like:

```
public class VerifyOwnership : IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        foreach(var parameter in filterContext.ActionParameters)
        {
            var owned  = paramter.Value as IHaveAnOwner;
            if(owned != null)
            {                    
                if(owned.OwnerId != WebSecurity.CurrentUserId)
                {
                    // ... not found or access denied
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {

    }
}
```

That assumes models like Notebook implement a specific interface.

```
public interface IHaveAnOwner
{
    int OwnerId { get; set; }
}
```

Blowdart has a good point that a user could tamper with the OwnerId in a post. I'm sure  they could tamper with their auth ticket, too, but they'd have to know the other user's ticket and tamper with both to get the IDs to match for another user, I believe.

Comment: That's a cool solution - would have to code around newly created objects and a few other catches I'm sure

Answer (score 3):

The filter sounds like an ok approach, but it's somewhat limited. It would be nice if you could have a filter like this:

```
[RequireOwnership<Notebook>(n => n.UserProfileId)]
```

...but `Attributes` are limited in which data types are allowed, and I don't think that generics are allowed either. So you could have a `[RequireOwnership]` attribute that works by inspecting model properties using reflection, or you could create a custom validator instead, where your model looks like this:

```
public class Notebook
{
    [MatchesCurrentUserId]
    public int UserProfileId { get; set; }
}
```

Then your `ModelState.IsValid` check should suffice.

**Edit:**

Another option occurred to me. You could use a filter in conjunction with an attribute on your model (doesn't have to be a `ValidationAttribute`). The filter could inspect your request models and check for properties with `[MatchesCurrentUserId]`, comparing with the current user ID.

Comment: I've been back and forth with the idea of using a ValidationAttribute. I like the idea but at the same time feel like I should be returning Http 401 Unauthorized vs a validation error. Any thoughts?

Comment: The unauthorized response is definitely better. You could inspect the validation results and determine whether a 401 response should be returned. Or perhaps the validation attribute could throw an exception that would ultimately translate to a 401 response (like maybe throwing an `HttpException`)

Comment: Ahhh, but if you have to inspect them then are you just writing more code in the controller again?

Comment: Jacob, the 3rd option of decorating the model property with an attribute and using a filter to inspect and verify sounds decent. Would the attribute be just sort of an identifier with no actual logic, my assumption would be yes.

Comment: Yes, it would just be an identifier. @OdeToCode's solution using an interface is also a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

When I have done things like this in the past it really hasn't been much better. For our projects we would have a method that would accept a `Notebook` object and check it against the currently logged in user.

You could overload this method with all of your different object types and use a consistent method for checking access. Sorry, that's the best way I know of.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Notebook notebook)
{
    if(!SessionUser.LoggedInUser.CheckAccess(notebook))
        return HttpNotFound();

    //Other code...
}
```

P.S. `SessionUser` is a custom class we had basically just to manage whoever is logged in at the time. You could write something similar but don't expect it to be in .NET by default.